# AWS API Gateway: Get or Post for querying

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, get, aws-api-gateway

I am creating an API, which is going to list me products page by page with given filter conditions.

To give a brief description, it holds a AWS Lambda behind AWS API.

I am not able to decide whether to use GET or POST.

- Because querying is considered a **GET** operation, so this is natural choice. But having a GET operation with JSON body is not very convenient way. So basically, I am left with the choice of putting it in URL.
- About **POST**, I wont be able to use API cache in future if required.

Please suggest the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GET`.

Many clients do not support the body for `GET`, use URL params instead of the body. `GET` can be cached, bookmarked. Also `GET` is a natural choice as you are not updating any data.